# template in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, node-red

I would recuperate the value of a variable in the template node. The value of this variable is calculated in a function node.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure "recuperate" is the right word. Can you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a variable in the function node. I would use the value of this variable in my template node.
The variable is an array. I need this array in my template node to make a chart.

Comment: @AKX  I have a variable in the function node. I would use the value of this variable in my template node. The variable is an array. I need this array in my template node to make a chart.

Answer (score 1):

The way to pass your array out of the `function` node, so it can be used inside the `ui_template` node, is to return it as the payload -- like so:

```
var array = [12, 34, 56]; // or whatever
msg.payload = array;
return msg;
```

In your `ui_template` code, you can then use the Angular `ng-repeat` directive to iterate over the payload array -- for example, to put them into a simple 1-column table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in msg.payload">
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But, if your goal is to plot them on a line or bar chart, it would be far easier to use the built-in dashboard `ui_chart` node.

Comment: Whithout the table balise I would use the msg.payload directly in the template node.